# lenses, fclabels, data-accessor - which library for structure access and mutation is better

Tags: data-structures, haskell, record, lenses

There are at least three popular libraries for accessing and manipulating fields of records. The ones I know of are: data-accessor, fclabels and lenses.

Personally I started with data-accessor and I'm using them now. However recently on haskell-cafe there was an opinion of fclabels being superior.

Therefore I'm interested in comparison of those three (and maybe more) libraries.

Comment: As of today, [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package has the richest functionality and documentation, so if you don't mind its complexity and dependencies, it's the way to go.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

There are at least 4 libraries that I am aware of providing lenses.

The notion of a lens is that it provides something isomorphic to

```
data Lens a b = Lens (a -> b) (b -> a -> a)
```

providing two functions: a getter, and a setter

```
get (Lens g _) = g
put (Lens _ s) = s
```

subject to three laws:

First, that if you put something, you can get it back out

```
get l (put l b a) = b
```

Second that getting and then setting doesn't change the answer

```
put l (get l a) a = a
```

And third, putting twice is the same as putting once, or rather, that the second put wins.

```
put l b1 (put l b2 a) = put l b1 a
```

Note, that the type system isn't sufficient to check these laws for you, so you need to ensure them yourself no matter what lens implementation you use.

Many of these libraries also provide a bunch of extra combinators on top, and usually some form of template haskell machinery to automatically generate lenses for the fields of simple record types.

With that in mind, we can turn to the different implementations:

***Implementations***

**fclabels**

[fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels) is perhaps the most easily reasoned about of the lens libraries, because its `a :-> b` can be directly translated to the above type. It provides a [Category](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Category.html) instance for `(:->)` which is useful as it allows you to compose lenses. It also provides a lawless `Point` type which generalizes the notion of a lens used here, and some plumbing for dealing with isomorphisms.

One hindrance to the adoption of `fclabels` is that the main package includes the template-haskell plumbing, so the package is not Haskell 98, and it also requires the (fairly non-controversial) `TypeOperators` extension.

**data-accessor**

[Edit: `data-accessor` is no longer using this representation, but has moved to a form similar to that of `data-lens`. I'm keeping this commentary, though.]

[data-accessor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-accessor) is somewhat more popular than `fclabels`, in part because it *is* Haskell 98. However, its choice of internal representation makes me throw up in my mouth a little bit.

The type `T` it uses to represent a lens is internally defined as

```
newtype T r a = Cons { decons :: a -> r -> (a, r) }
```

Consequently, in order to `get` the value of a lens, you must submit an undefined value for the 'a' argument! This strikes me as an incredibly ugly and ad hoc implementation.

That said, Henning has included the template-haskell plumbing to automatically generate the accessors for you in a separate '[data-accessor-template](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-accessor-template)' package.

It has the benefit of a decently large set of packages that already employ it, being Haskell 98, and providing the all-important `Category` instance, so if you don't pay attention to how the sausage is made, this package is actually pretty reasonable choice.

**lenses**

Next, there is the [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lenses/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-Lenses.html) package, which observes that a lens can provide a state monad homomorphism between two state monads, by definining lenses directly *as* such monad homomorphisms.

If it actually bothered to provide a type for its lenses, they would have a rank-2 type like:

```
newtype Lens s t = Lens (forall a. State t a -> State s a)
```

As a result, I rather don't like this approach, as it needlessly yanks you out of Haskell 98 (if you want a type to provide to your lenses in the abstract) and deprives you of the `Category` instance for lenses, which would let you compose them with `.`. The implementation also requires multi-parameter type classes.

Note, all of the other lens libraries mentioned here provide some combinator or can be used to provide this same state focalization effect, so nothing is gained by encoding your lens directly in this fashion.

Furthermore, the side-conditions stated at the start don't really have a nice expression in this form. As with 'fclabels' this does provide template-haskell method for automatically generating lenses for a record type directly in the main package.

Because of the lack of `Category` instance, the baroque encoding, and the requirement of template-haskell in the main package, this is my least favorite implementation.

**data-lens**

[Edit: As of 1.8.0, these have moved from the comonad-transformers package to data-lens]

My [`data-lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens) package provides lenses in terms of the [Store](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/1.5.2.6/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Store-Lazy.html) comonad.

```
newtype Lens a b = Lens (a -> Store b a)
```

where

```
data Store b a = Store (b -> a) b
```

Expanded this is equivalent to

```
newtype Lens a b = Lens (a -> (b, b -> a))
```

You can view this as factoring out the common argument from the getter and the setter to return a pair consisting of the result of retrieving the element, and a setter to put a new value back in. This offers the computational benefit that the 'setter' here can recycle some of the work used to get the value out, making for a more efficient 'modify' operation than in the `fclabels` definition, especially when accessors are chained.

There is also a nice theoretical justification for this representation, because the subset of 'Lens' values that satisfy the 3 laws stated in the beginning of this response are precisely those lenses for which the wrapped function is a 'comonad coalgebra' for the store comonad. This transforms 3 hairy laws for a lens `l` down to 2 nicely pointfree equivalents:

```
extract . l = id
duplicate . l = fmap l . l
```

This approach was first noted and described in Russell O'Connor's [`Functor` is to `Lens` as `Applicative` is to `Biplate`: Introducing Multiplate](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2841) and was [blogged about based on a preprint](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/lenses-are-the-coalgebras-for-the-costate-comonad/) by Jeremy Gibbons.

It also includes a number of combinators for working with lenses strictly and some stock lenses for containers, such as `Data.Map`.

So the lenses in `data-lens` form a `Category` (unlike the `lenses` package), are Haskell 98 (unlike `fclabels`/`lenses`), are sane (unlike the back end of `data-accessor`) and provide a slightly more efficient implementation, [`data-lens-fd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-fd) provides the functionality for working with MonadState for those willing to step outside of Haskell 98, and the template-haskell machinery is now available via [`data-lens-template`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-template).

***Update 6/28/2012: Other Lens Implementation Strategies***

**Isomorphism Lenses**

There are two other lens encodings worth considering. The first gives a nice theoretical way to view a lens as a way to break a structure into the value of the field, and 'everything else'.

Given a type for isomorphisms

```
data Iso a b = Iso { hither :: a -> b, yon :: b -> a }
```

such that valid members satisfy `hither . yon = id`, and `yon . hither = id`

We can represent a lens with:

```
data Lens a b = forall c. Lens (Iso a (b,c))
```

These are primarily useful as a way to think about the meaning of lenses, and we can use them as a reasoning tool to explain other lenses.

**van Laarhoven Lenses**

We can model lenses such that they can be composed with `(.)` and `id`, even without a `Category` instance by using

```
type Lens a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a
```

as the type for our lenses.

Then defining a lens is as easy as:

```
_2 f (a,b) = (,) a <$> f b
```

and you can validate for yourself that function composition is lens composition.

I've recently written on how you can further [generalize van Laarhoven lenses](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses/) to get lens families that can change the types of fields, just by generalizing this signature to

```
type LensFamily a b c d = forall f. Functor f => (c -> f d) -> a -> f b
```

This does have the unfortunate consequence that the best way to talk about lenses is to use rank 2 polymorphism, but you don't need to use that signature directly when defining lenses.

The `Lens` I defined above for `_2` is actually a `LensFamily`.

```
_2 :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> (c,a) -> f (c, b)
```

I've written a library that includes lenses, lens families, and other generalizations including getters, setters, folds and traversals. It is available on hackage as the  [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.

Again, a big advantage of this approach is that library maintainers can actually create lenses in this style in your libraries without incurring any lens library dependency whatsoever, by just supplying functions with type `Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a`, for their particular types 'a' and 'b'. This greatly lowers the cost of adoption.

Since you don't need to actually use the package to define new lenses, it takes a lot of pressure off my earlier concerns about keeping the library Haskell 98.

Comment: very nice writeup! what do you think about the [fields](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fields) library?

Comment: I think it is fairly extension heavy for what it accomplishes. =/

Comment: I like the fclabels for its optimistic approach `:->`

Comment: The articles [Inessential Guide to data-accessor](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/04/inessential-guide-to-data-accessor/) and [Inessential guide to fclabels](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/04/inessential-guide-to-fclabels/) might be noteworthy

Comment: The reason `fclabels` has the type `Point` is to provide parallel composition with its `Applicative` instance, next to the sequential composition that the `Category` instance of `Lens` provides.

Comment: @Sjoerd Visscher: Don't get me wrong. I like Point. It is an interesting type. It can also be useful to describe things like aggregators that add a number to a counter, etc. But are no laws for reasoning about what would form a valid Point as opposed to a valid Lens, because get and put have become unrelated. Hence 'lawless'. ;) 

As a side note, fmapL doesn't generate valid lenses by the lens laws. I realized that when I added scalacheck properties to my lenses in scala.

Comment: For `fmapL` consider using it to lift any old `Lens` into the `Maybe` `Applicative`. When you go to put `Just foo` into `Nothing` the result remains `Nothing`, so when you go to get the value of that field with your lens you get `Nothing` rather than your `Just foo` back and the first law fails.

Comment: @EdwardKmett I was just pointing out a feature that fclabels has that is unique among the lenses packages (afaik), and therefore should be mentioned in a thorough comparison.

Perhaps the documentation should mention that `fmapL` only creates proper lenses with container types with a fixed number of 'holes', like `Vec n`, which have a zip-like `Applicative` instance. However, the lens that is created is the most natural one possible for `Maybe`, in some vague sense that should probably be made more concrete.

Comment: Is being Haskell 1998 compatible important? Because it makes compiler development easier? And shouldn't we switch to talking about Haskell 2010 instead?

Comment: Oh no!  I was the original author of `data-accessor`, and then I passed it over to Henning and stopped paying attention.  The `a -> r -> (a,r)` representation also makes me uncomfortable, and my original implementation was just like your `Lens` type.  Heeennnninngg!!

Comment: Yairchu: it is mostly so your library might have a chance to work with a compiler other than ghc. Nobody else *has* template Haskell. 2010 doesn't add anything relevant here.

Comment: Sjoerd: the problem with Point is that getting and setting have nothing to do with one another. I'd just as soon use the applicative instance for (->) e to compose getters than use an applicative that performed the two unrelated tasks of fanning out inputs and composing outputs, because any Point built this way won't be able to be wrapped back into a valid lens anyways.

Comment: Sjoerd: what you are looking for is the preservation of limits. Representable functors have this property, see the representable-functors package. While the definition for Maybe given by fmapL is 'as close to a lens as you can get' it still isn't a lens. ;)

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: I added [`repLens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/0.4.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html#v:repLens) providing the safer `fmapL` to [representable-functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors)

Comment: Seems to me like the information on `data-accessor` is no longer accurate: since 0.2.1.8 it uses [`newtype T r a  =  Cons {decons :: r -> (a, a -> r)}`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-accessor/0.2.2.2/doc/html/src/Data-Accessor-Private.html#T).

Comment: @EdwardKmett I see a typo in your definition of _2. Shouldn't it be `_2 f (a,b) = (,) a <$> f b`?

Comment: As an addendum, I would like to add that the lens type of data-accessor has been changed to `newtype T r a  =  Cons {decons :: r -> (a, a -> r)}`, which is roughly isomorphic to that used in data-lens.