# Statically "extend" a record-ish data type without indirection hassle

Tags: functional-programming, nested, ocaml, sml, records

I am currently working with a three-level process for which I need some information to flow being accessed and updated. The information is also three-leveled, in such a way that a process at one level may need to access/update information at its level and at higher levels.

```
type info_0 = { ... fields ... }
type info_1 = { ... fields ... }
type info_2 = { ... fields ... }
```

`fun0` will do some stuff with an `info_0`, then pass it to `fun1` along with an `info_1`, then get back the resulting `info_0` and proceed, calling another `fun1` with another `info_1`.
The same happens at the lower level.

---

My current representation has

```
type info_0 = { ... fields ... }
type info_1 = { i0: info_0; ... fields ... }
type info_2 = { i1: info_1; ... fields ... }
```

In `fun2`, updating `info_0` get pretty messy:

```
let fun2 (i2: info_2): info_2 =
  {
    i2 with
      i1 = {
        i2.i1 with
          i0 = update_field0 i2.i1.i0
      }
  }
```

---

Something simpler would be:

```
type info_0 = { ... fields ... }
type info_1 = { ... fields ... }
type info_2 = { ... fields ... }
type info_01 = info_0 * info_1
type info_012 = info_0 * info_1 * info_2

let fun2 (i0, i1, i2): info_012 =
  (update_field0 i0, i1, i2)
```

---

Does the last solution look good?

Is there an even better solution to this kind of problem? (for instance, one where I could write a function that can handle updating a `field0`, no matter whether it's dealing with a `info_0`, `info_1` or `info_2`)

Would OCaml modules help? (I could include a `Sig0` inside `Sig1` for instance...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is an idiomatic way of *updating nested immutable data structures*. <strike>I don't know any relevant work in OCaml, but</strike> there are a few techniques available in Scala/Haskell including **Zippers**, **Tree rewriting**, and **Functional lenses**:

[Cleaner way to update nested structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures)

[Is there a Haskell idiom for updating a nested data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365425/is-there-a-haskell-idiom-for-updating-a-nested-data-structure)

For F#, a descendant of OCaml, [functional lenses](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html) gives a nice solution. Therefore, lenses is the most relevant approach here. You can get the idea of using it from this thread:

[Updating nested immutable data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179485/updating-nested-immutable-data-structures)

since F# record syntax is almost the same as that of OCaml.

**EDIT:**

As @Thomas mentioned in his comment, there is a complete implementation of lenses in OCaml available [here](https://github.com/astrada/gapi-ocaml). And particularly, [gapiLens.mli](https://github.com/astrada/gapi-ocaml/blob/master/src/gapi/gapiLens.mli) is of our interest.

Comment: Thanks, this http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html deals with exactly my issue!

Comment: Yes, it does. I hope someone will build a similar library to work in general cases in OCaml.

Comment: The unsatisfying thing is, at my call site, I still have to remember where I am to call the right functions, say `bookEditorCarMileage.Set` or just `editorCarMileage.Set` or `carMileage.Set`... With the class approach and inheritance I can just `obj#set_mileage` whatever `obj` is.

Comment: I admit that you still have to write boilerplate codes in this approach. But I prefer staying immutable, managing mutable update of class hierarchy is a huge pain. When I use a functional language, I try to avoid mutation at all cost.

Comment: if you want lenses, you can find a pretty complete implementation [here](https://github.com/astrada/gapi-ocaml)

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want the ability to treat a more complex value as though it was a simpler one.  This is (more or less) the essence of the OO model.  I usually try to avoid the OO subset of OCaml unless I really need it, but it does seem to meet your needs here.  You would have a base class corresponding to `info_0`.  The class `info_1` would be a subclass of `info_0`, and `info_2` would be a subclass of `info_1`.  It's worth thinking about, anyway.

Comment: Would the object model of OCaml work well with the immutable nature of the current code ? If mutability is not a problem, records can also be modified in place...

Comment: This is a good point.  I was thinking about the subtyping more than about mutability.  Something else to think about, for sure.

Comment: That looks like a decent solution: I lose record access syntax, but at the benefits of inheritance (I can define a getter/setter in class info_0, and inherit it in info_1). However, I forgot to mention that I needed immutable updates, as I sometimes need to do non-deterministic processes and then backtrack (keep only one of these), and I don't want to deal with this myself... So as @FabriceLeFessant mentioned, this won't really solve my problem.

Comment: @Ptival OCaml objects can be immutable just like records can be. What may be a problem is that in Jeffrey's model, the objects would replicate the information instead of pointing to each other, so your data may end up using significantly more memory.

Comment: @Gilles I need functional updates, with sharing, is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

[As Jeffrey Scofield suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379626/statically-extend-a-record-ish-data-type-without-indirection-hassle/9380661#9380661), You can save the hassle at use and update time by using classes: make `info_1` a derived class, and a subtype, of `info_0`, and so on.

```
class info_1 = object
  inherit info_0
  val a_1_1 : int
  …
  method update_a_1_1 v = {<a_1_1 = v>}
end
…
let x : info_1 = new info_1 … in
let y = x#update_a_1_1 42 in
…
```

The downside of this direct object approach is that all the data in an object is copied if you update any of the fields; you can't share the `info_0` pieces between `x` and `y`.

You can use objects and retain the sharing behavior from your design with records, but the boilerplate at definition time and the constant run-time overhead become larger.

```
class info_1 = object
  val zero : info_0
  method get_a_0_1 = zero#get_a_0_1
  method update_a_0_1 = {<zero = zero#update_a_0_1>}
  val a_1_1 : int
  method get_a_1_1 = a_1_1
  method update_a_1_1 v = {<a_1_1 = v>}
end
let x : info_1 = new info_1 … in
let y = x#update_a_1_1 42 in
…
```