# Function to create one of two record types dynamically

Tags: ocaml

I have this OO situation I'm trying to implement in Ocaml:
Two classes `X1` and `X2`, both subtyping `X` (`X1 <: X` and `X2 <: X`) and I want to write a function that dynamically returns an `X` that will either be an `X1` or an `X2`.

However I heard it's usually good to avoid classes in Ocaml and use modules instead, so I'm trying to represent my problem like this (overly simplified but still makes the point):
Two modules `X1` and `X2`, and I want my function to dynamically decide between returning either an `X1.t` or an `X2.t`.

```
module type X = sig
  type choice
  type t
  (* some methods we don't care about in this instance, like
     val modifySomething : t -> t *)
end

module Xbase = struct
  type choice = Smth | SmthElse
end

module X1 = (
struct
  include Xbase
  type t = { foo : int; bar : int }
end : X)

module X2 = (
struct
  include Xbase
  type t = { foo : int; star : int }
end : X)

module XStatic =
struct
  (* construct either an X1.t or X2.t from the string *)
  let read : string -> 'a =
    function
    | "X1" -> { X1.foo = 0, bar = 0 }
    | "X2" -> { X2.foo = 1, star = 1 }
end
```

But this fails with `Error: Unbound record field label X1.foo` in the `read` function.
I've tried different ways of arranging it, such as using `let open X1 in { foo = 0, ... }` but to no avail.

Is my approach to this fundamentally wrong (i.e. should I be using classes because this is impossible/unpractical with modules) or am I just missing something trivial?

Edit: Clarified the problem I'm trying to solve and renamed `module X` to `module XBase` to differentiate it from `module type X`.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach is to use a sum type (disclaimer: I didn't try to compile the code):

```
module X1 = struct
  type t = { foo : int; bar : string }
  let modify_foo = ...
end
module X2 = struct
  type t = { foo : int; star : bool }
  let modify_foo = ...
end
type x1_or_x2 =
  | Left of X1.t
  | Right of X2.t

let read = function
  | "X1" -> Left { X1.foo = 1; bar = "bar" }
  | "X2" -> Right { X2.foo = 1; star = true }

let modify_foo = function
  | Left x1 -> Left (X1.modify_foo x1)
  | Right x2 -> Right (X2.modify_foo x2)
```

If you want to take advantage of the fact that `X1.t` and `X2.t` share some common structure, you can factorize the types. The idea is that they are isomorphic to product types, respectively `common_part * specific_to_x1` and `common_part * specific_to_x2`. The `x1_or_x2` type is therefore `(common * specific_to_x1) + (common * specific_to_x2)`, which is equivalent to `common * (specific_to_x1 + specific_to_x2)`.

```
type common = { foo : int }
let modify_foo_common : common -> common = ...

type specific_x1 = { bar : string }
type specific_x2 = { star : bool }

type x1_or_x2 = common * specific_x1_or_x2
and specific_x1_or_x2 =
  | Left of X1.t
  | Right of X2.t

let read = function
  | "X1" -> { foo = 1 }, Left { bar = "bar" }
  | "X2" -> { foo = 1 }, Right { star = true }

let modify_foo (common, specific) = (modify_foo_common common, specific)
```

This way, definitions that act on the common part are not duplicated but can be declared once.

PS: also see this very related question in which you could be interested and which has a nice answer (lenses!): [Ptival: Statically “extend” a record-ish data type without indirection hassle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379626/statically-extend-a-record-ish-data-type-without-indirection-hassle)

Answer (score 1):

The error `Unbound record field label X1.foo` is due to the fact that `X1` and `X2` have module signature `Xbase`, which only has the type `choice` (and not the type `t`).
I.e. the syntax `: X` hides all values and types of `X1` which are not part of the `Xbase` signature.

But even if you correct this error, something more important will appear: what is the return type of function `read`? It can't be both `X1.t` and `X2.t`.

Comment: On the contrary, `module type X` does have `type t` (right at the beginning) -- sorry it's confusing that I named both the initial module and its type with the same name.

Comment: Re the 2nd paragraph: I'm trying to mimic something akin to class subtyping. `X1 <: X` and `X2 <: X`, where I want to create either X1 or X2 dynamically and return it as an X. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've coerced your modules `X1` and `X2` to the module type `X`, you have lost the information of how inner types are structured when outside these modules. The rest of the code (that is everything but the content of the modules) won't be able to know what `X1.t` and `X2.t` are made of: these types become *abstract* for everything else but their own respective modules.

The OOP approach of your problem would be perhaps to make default constructors, and call them when needed. In your case, it means defining the default values in the modules, add a declaration in the interface (the module type), so that outside code can still create values of these types.

```
module type X = sig
    type t
    val default : unit -> t
    (* etc. *)
end;;

module X1 : X = struct
    include XBase     
    type t = {foo : int; bar : int}
    (* here I can change fields adlib *)
    let default () = {foo = 0; bar = 1}
   (* ... *)
end;;
(* here I don't have access to X1.t fields anymore *)
```

Note that if your types don't hold mutable fields or references, you could make `default` as simple values of `t`, rather than functions, but maybe you wish to keep the possibility of having such fields in other modules.

The main point here is that you need either to keep your types public or provide ways to construct and manipulate values (the later already being implemented to some extent in your code I suppose) for your abstracted types.

If you don't or cannot change the module type `X`, then you could perhaps enforce the signature at the upper level, using a mli file to do the coercion for other modules than the one containing `X1` and `X2` (that is, if your code is following such a design).

Yet another way is to add the type information regarding `t` when doing the coercion. For instance, here's a declaration of the type of `X1` with the `choice` type explicited (provided it already exists in `X`):

```
module X1 : X with type choice = XBase.choice =
struct
   (* body of the X1 module *)
end;;
(* now I can access X1.choice constants from here, if XBase.choice is visible too *)
```

You could do something similar with its type `t`, and then have access to its content from outside code. From a design standpoint, it's obviously not the best way to handle the problem, if you already provide operators in the modules to manipulate values of type `t`.