# Functionally updating arbitrarily nested data structures with lenses

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-lens

Say I have a data structure representing a Bag of Holding, which can hold multiple items. The user could place another Bag of Holding in this bag, and that bag could contain other bags, or even bags containing bags. Is there a lens for functionally updating arbitrarily nested bags, e.g. removing item foo from a bag inside a bag inside a bag inside a bag? Note that level of nesting, as well as the total depth of the tree, is dynamic, not known at compile time. Other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179485/updating-nested-immutable-data-structures) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365425/is-there-a-haskell-idiom-for-updating-a-nested-data-structure) seem to only deal with statically-known levels of nesting.

What I'm looking for can be done in Clojure with the [update-in function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in), by generating a vector of accessors dynamically to pass to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of "Bag of Holding" wasn't precise but I think this is close to what you meant. The basic idea is to traverse into a child bag using a `[Int]` (similar to the `Ixed` instance for `Tree`) and use the `At` instance for `Map` to edit the items.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}

import           Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Map     as M

data Bag k a = Bag (M.Map k a) [Bag k a]
  deriving (Show)

-- | Lens onto top level items of a bag.
items :: Lens' (Bag k a) (M.Map k a)
items f (Bag k a) = f k <&> \k' -> Bag k' a

-- | Use 'At' instance for 'M.Map' to edit top level items.
atItem :: Ord k => k -> Lens' (Bag k a) (Maybe a)
atItem k = items . at k

type instance Index (Bag k a)   = [Int]
type instance IxValue (Bag k a) = Bag k a
instance Ixed (Bag k a) where
  ix is0 f = go is0 where
    -- Use the `Ixed` instance for lists to traverse over
    -- item `i` in the list of bags.
    go (i:is) (Bag m bs) = Bag m <$> ix i (go is) bs
    go _      b          = f b
  {-# INLINE ix #-}

mybag :: Bag String Char
mybag =
  Bag [("a1",'a')] -- ix []
   [ Bag [] []     -- ix [0]
   , Bag []        -- ix [1]
     [ Bag [("foo", 'x'), ("bar",'y')] [] -- ix [1,0]
     , Bag [("FOO", 'X'), ("BAR",'Y')] [] -- ix [1,1]
     ]
  ]
```

So now if we want to delete the "FOO" item from bag `[1,1]`:

```
> mybag & ix [1,1] . atItem "FOO" .~ Nothing
Bag (fromList [("a1",'a')])
  [Bag (fromList []) []
  ,Bag (fromList [])
     [Bag (fromList [("bar",'y'),("foo",'x')]) []
     ,Bag (fromList [("BAR",'Y')]) []]]
```

or insert "foobar" into bag `[1,0]`:

```
> mybag & ix [1,0] . atItem "foobar" ?~ 'z'
Bag (fromList [("a1",'a')])
  [Bag (fromList []) []
  ,Bag (fromList [])
    [Bag (fromList [("bar",'y'),("foo",'x'),("foobar",'z')]) []
    ,Bag (fromList [("BAR",'Y'),("FOO",'X')]) []]]
```

---

Actually my definition of a `Bag` was just a specialised `Tree`:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Lens

type Bag k a = Tree (M.Map k a)

atItem :: Ord k => k -> Lens' (Bag k a) (Maybe a)
atItem k = root . at k

subBag :: [Int] -> Traversal' (Bag k a) (Bag k a)
subBag (i:is) = branches . ix i . subBag is
subBag _      = id
```

This can be used the same as before expect use `subBag` instead of `ix`. The definition of `subBag` is probably clearer written this way.

In fact you don't need to write any new functions because the `Ixed` instance for `Tree` is the same as `subBag is . root`, so editing can be done by:

```
> mybag & ix [1,1] . at "FOO" .~ Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the `Bag` datatype is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Reified
import Data.Monoid

type Item = Int

data Bag = Bag 
    {
        _items :: [Item]
    ,   _bags :: [Bag]
    } deriving (Show)

$(makeLenses ''Bag)

exampleBag :: Bag
exampleBag = Bag [1,2] [Bag [] [], Bag [] [Bag [3] [Bag [0] []]]]
```

In [`Control.Lens.Reified`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedTraversal), there's the `ReifiedTraversal` newtype which is used to store traversals in containers. We can declare a `Monoid` instance for those traversals that start and end in the same data type:

```
instance Monoid (ReifiedTraversal s s s s) where
    mempty = Traversal id
    mappend (Traversal t1) (Traversal t2) = Traversal (t1 . t2)
```

`mappend` is just the composition of traversals (kinda like how the [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) monoid works.)

Now we can define traversals from `Bag` to `Bag` at run time using lists:

```
lensList :: [ReifiedTraversal' Bag Bag]
lensList = 
    [ Traversal $ bags . ix 1
    , Traversal $ bags . ix 0
    , Traversal $ bags . ix 0
    ]
```

And test it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ over ((runTraversal $ mconcat lensList) . items . ix 0) succ exampleBag
```

We could also define a [`Plated`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:parts) instance for `Bag`, that would let us do things like listing all the bags in the hierarchy, or perform [paramorphisms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:para) on bags. A "bagamorphism", if you will.