# Create new record with change in one value

Tags: haskell, record

Suppose my record (with large number of fields) is defined like this:

```
data Sample_Record = Sample_Record { record_field1 :: Int,
                                     record_field2 :: Int,
                                     record_field3 :: Float
                                    }

a = Sample_Record { record_field1 = 4,
                    record_field2 = 5,
                    record_field3 = 5.4
                  }
```

Can I make a new record of the type `Sample_Record` from `a` which has one of it's field modified ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Haskell idiom for updating a nested data structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365425/is-there-a-haskell-idiom-for-updating-a-nested-data-structure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. We have a lot of ways. The simple is

```
foo b = b {record_field1 = 1}

> foo a
 Sample_Record { record_field1 = 1,record_field2 = 5, record_field3 = 5.4 }
```

We have some extensions.
WildCards allow not to use all record in pattern,

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
bar b@(Sample_Record {record_field1 = 1,..}) = b {record_field1 = 10}
bar b@(Sample_Record {record_field1 = 2,..}) = b {record_field1 = 20}
```

With `NamedFieldPuns` extension we could use record fields as values without extra boilerplate (`f (C {a=a}) = a` is same as `f (C {a}) = a`)

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
baz b@(Sample_Record {record_field1, record_field2, record_field3 = 0}) = 
   b{ record_field3 = record_field1 + record_field2 }
```