# How can I concisely modify a record's field?

Tags: haskell, record

```
data Person = Person
  {
    name :: String
  , counter :: Int
  }

incrementPersonCounter :: Person -> Person
incrementPersonCounter p@(Person _ c) = p { counter = c + 1 }
```

Is there a more concise way of doing the above? Is there a function I could use, where I specify the record, one of its fields (`name` / `counter` in this case) and a function to apply to the return value?

---

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
applyRecord r f f' = r
  { f = f' (f r) }
```

Though this won't work because:

```
error: Not in scope: ‘f’
   |
13 |   { f = f' (f r) }
```

Comment: This is the sort of problem lenses were invented to solve.

Comment: See also [Is there a Haskell idiom for updating a nested data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7365425/791604), though I hesitate to mark this as a duplicate because the modern answer has changed so much. This question has a much better exposition of the modern answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of generalizing `incrementPersonCounter` is to abstract over the modification function:

```
modifyPersonCounter :: (Int -> Int) -> Person -> Person
modifyPersonCounter f p = (\c -> p { counter = c}) $ f (counter p)
```

In fact, a common pattern is to abstract as well over the *effect* we want to perform in the field:

```
counterLens :: forall f. Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> (Person -> f Person)
counterLens f p = (\c -> p { counter = c }) <$> f (counter p)
```

For example, we might want to read the counter increase from console, or from a database (both `IO` effects).

We can give a [synonym](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:Lens) to the type of functions that, given a (possibly effectful) way of changing a field, return a function that transforms the whole record:

```
type Lens' a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
```

To modify a record *purely*, now we need an auxiliary function we can call [`over`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:over), which only needs to be defined once:

```
over :: Lens' a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
over l f p = runIdentity $ l (Identity . f) p
```

For example:

```
*Main> over counterLens (+1) (Person "foo" 40)
Person {name = "foo", counter = 41}
```

---

We have abstracted over the modification function and its possible effects, but we still need to define these "lenses" for each field, which is annoying. In practice, people use [Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeLenses) to define them automatically and avoid boilerplate.

But what if we wanted a *single* function that let us specify the name of the field? That is, sadly, more complex. You need a way to pass type-level strings as arguments, and a [multi-parameter type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/overloaded-records-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-OverloadedRecords.html#t:HasField) that encodes the relationship between a field's name, the type of the record, and the type of the field. There are [some packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/overloaded-records-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-OverloadedRecords.html) which do that (again, with Template Haskell help for the boilerplate) but to my knowledge they are not widely used.

The main library for lenses is called [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), and there is also [microlens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens), an alternative with a lighter dependency footprint. They are interoperable: lenses defined using one library work with the other.

Comment: "generic-lens" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Fields.html#t:HasField provides a `field` lens that works for all records which derive `Generic`, without the need for Template Haskell http://kcsongor.github.io/generic-lens/

Answer (score 5):

Using [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) you can write it like this:

```
incrementPersonCounter :: Person -> Person
incrementPersonCounter = counter +~ 1
```

Example:

```
λ> incrementPersonCounter $ Person "foo" 42
Person {_name = "foo", _counter = 43}
```

---

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Lib where

import Control.Lens

data Person = Person
  {
    _name :: String
  , _counter :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Person

incrementPersonCounter :: Person -> Person
incrementPersonCounter = counter +~ 1
```