# Functional lenses

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lenses

Could someone explain functional lenses to me? It's a surprisingly difficult subject to google for and I haven't made any progress. All I know is that they provide similar get/set functionality than in OO.

Comment: There is [a nice introduction to lenses](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q) by Edward Kmett on YouTube. The examples are in Scala, but it shouldn't be too hard to follow.

Comment: Yup, tried to watch those, but having enough time while I'm still alert, is not so easy :P

Comment: @Jochen: The lenses described there don't really have much in common with the lenses this question is about.

Comment: Here is nice introduction using pictures: [Lenses in Pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-07-22-lenses-in-pictures.html).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A lens consists of two functions, a getter and a setter:

```
data Lens a b = Lens { getter :: a -> b, setter :: b -> a -> a }
```

For example, we might have lenses for the first and second parts of a pair:

```
fstLens :: Lens (a, b) a
fstLens = Lens fst $ \x (a, b) -> (x, b)

sndLens :: Lens (a, b) b
sndLens = Lens snd $ \x (a, b) -> (a, x)
```

The real convenience of lenses is that they compose:

```
compose :: Lens b c -> Lens a b -> Lens a c
compose f g = Lens (getter f . getter g) $
                   \c a -> setter g (setter f c (getter g a)) a
```

And they mechanically convert to `State` transitions:

```
lensGet :: MonadState s m => Lens s a -> m a
lensGet = gets . getter

lensSet :: MonadState s m => Lens s b -> b -> m ()
lensSet f = modify . setter f

lensMod :: MonadState s m => Lens s b -> (b -> b) -> m ()
lensMod f g = modify $ setter f =<< g . getter f

(+=) :: (MonadState s m, Num b) => Lens s b -> b -> m ()
f += x = lensMod f (+ x)
```

Comment: Your compose example didn't typecheck. GHC infers; Lens a a -> Lens a a -> Lens a a

Comment: Masse: I accidentally flipped the `f` and `g`.

Comment: It still doesn't type check into a->c. It infers into compose ::  Lens a b -> Lens a a -> Lens a b

Answer (score 12):

See the answer to question [lenses, fclabels, data-accessor - which library for structure access and mutation is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio) - it has a very clear explanation on lenses.

Also, the documentation for the [Data.Lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lenses/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-Lenses.html) and [fclabel](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fclabels/1.0.4/doc/html/Data-Label.html) libraries give some good examples of them being used.