# Haskell -- Chaining two states using StateT monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have two or more independent states to track in one Haskell application.

I am declaring two new type classes using

```
type MonadTuple m = MonadState (Int, Int) m
type MonadBool m = MonadState Bool m
```

The monad transformer stack is declared as

```
type Stack = StateT (Int, Int) (StateT Bool IO) ()
```

I intend to use the stack as such

```
ret :: Stack
ret = apply

apply :: (MonadTuple m, MonadBool m) => m ()
apply = undefined
```

The complier is unhappy because it cannot match `Bool` with `(Int, Int)` when trying to check if `Stack` conforms to `MonadBool`.

I am aware of the solution given in the [Combining multiple states in StateT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915923/combining-multiple-states-in-statet). Are there any simpler solutions other than **arrows** or **global state with lens**?

Appendix:
The full code block is

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

type MonadTuple m = MonadState (Int, Int) m
type MonadBool m = MonadState Bool m

type Stack = StateT (Int, Int) (StateT Bool IO) ()

ret :: Stack
ret = apply

apply :: (MonadTuple m, MonadBool m) => m ()
apply = undefined
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you name this `Stack`?

Comment: I named it `Stack` to suggest a monad transformer `stack`.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't have a hardcoded `()` as value type.

Comment: I agree. Not hardcoding would be clearer if the transformer is used in a polymorphic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The definition of `MonadState`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/mtl-2.2.2/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#t:MonadState) has a functional dependency `m -> s`, which means that one monad `m` must have at most one instance of `MonadState s m`. Or, in plainer terms, the same monad cannot have two instances of `MonadState` for two different states, which is exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler solution:

```
apply :: (MonadTuple (t m), MonadBool m, MonadTrans t) => t m ()
apply = undefined
```

You can use `get` and `put` inside `apply` to touch the `(Int, Int)` state, and `lift get` and `lift . put` to touch the `Bool` state.

However, this requires that `StateT (Int, Int)` be the top-level transformer. If it is lower than the top, you need to encode the depth by putting the appropriate number of additional transformers in your type; e.g. if it was the third thing down then you would need

```
apply :: (MonadTuple (t1 (t2 (t3 m))), MonadBool m, MonadTrans t1, MonadTrans t2, MonadTrans t3) => t1 (t2 (t3 m)) ()
apply = undefined
```

and would need to use three `lift`s for every access to the `Bool` state, which quickly gets unwieldy and really loses the charm of mtl-style class-polymorphic programming.

A common alternative style is to expose an API that touches the two states but is not class polymorphic. For example,

```
type Stack = StateT (Int, Int) (StateT Bool IO)

getTuple :: Stack (Int, Int)
getTuple = get

getBool :: Stack Bool
getBool = lift get
```

(Similarly you'd add a `putTuple` and `putBool`.)

I guess with modern extensions you could also consider introducing your own class which does not have the fundep that `MonadState` has; e.g.

```
class MonadState2 s m where
    get2 :: m s
    put2 :: s -> m ()
```

You could then use a newtype to give two instances, to be disambiguated by type:

```
newtype Stack a = Stack (StateT (Int, Int) (StateT Bool IO) a)
instance MonadState2 Bool Stack where
    get2 = Stack (lift get)
    put2 = Stack . lift . put

instance MonadState2 (Int, Int) Stack where
    get2 = Stack get
    put2 = Stack . put
```

Callers would then write e.g. `get2 @Bool` or `get2 @(Int, Int)` if type inference didn't have enough information to pick which instance to use. But I suspect this would get old real fast.