Nested Tuple conversion to List
I have some very edgy behavior that I want to circumvent in python.
Imagine that you have such structure:
something = {
 "data":{"mytuple":(1,2,3)}
}

Now I would like to access that tuple, for that I can do hthe following:
myGetter = something['data']['mytuple']

If I check that the data are the same, it is returning True
myGetter is something['data']['mytuple'] ## True

When I try to then convert that variable to a list, it works, but my nested data is not changed.
I suspect it is coming from memory allocation and the fact that the tuple is immutable.
myGetter = list(myGetter)

type(myGetter) ## return list
type(something['data']['mytuple']) ## still tuple

myGetter is something['data']['mytuple'] ## now returns False

Is there any way to modify the variable I created so it is replicated to the nested structure ?

something['data']['mytuple'] = list(something['data']['mytuple'])? Is that what you are looking for?

Yeah, but indirectly, without knowing the full path, I have a wrapper around that may return only the tuple (or set) and I may not know the full path...

But you are asking to assign something to a key, so you need to know which key.

Ah OK. For you I need to apply the change in the structure itself.
Copying the structure and changing its type will not impact the parent structure.

@Pitchkrak you can't change the object itself. That isn't what you are doing by doing list(myGeter), that simply creates a new list object from the iterable (in this case, the tuple) you pass to it.

Note that myGetter is not a getter, which would be a function like lambda obj: obj["data"]["mytuple"].  What you are trying to do, though, puts me in mind of functional lenses. There is probably a way to define a single function that could be used to create a getter or a setter. For example, get(f)(something) == (1,2,3) and apply_to(f)(something)(list) == {'data': {'mytuple': [1,2,3]}}

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312477/1126841 for an example in Haskell)

Thank you all, yes, I am actually building such function at the moment in a package.
It is called the Simple Object Manager so I want to abstract these kind of reasoning and I wanted to know if there was way to simplify the modification of type for element nested.
It makes sense to me that it is not changing the type itself, I was wondering if it was possible by changing memory allocation or else...

If you change the memory allocation then you must tell the structure that it should no longer reference the earlier memory location, but the new one. This is what you do when you assign to a key. If you don't want to assign to the key, then you really say you don't want to change the memory location and are hinting at mutation. You cannot mutate a tuple, nor is your code trying to.

A variable is not an alias for the expression that was assigned to it, it's just a reference to the value. Assigning to the variable doesn't have any effect on the original expression.
