# Haskell dynamic data-type alteration

Tags: haskell

I have some haskell boilerplate that looks something like this:

```
data Configuration
    { confA :: Integer
    , confB :: Boolean
    , confC :: String }

x = (\arg opt -> opt{ confA=arg })
y = (\arg opt -> opt{ confB=arg })
z = (\arg opt -> opt{ confC=arg })
```

and I'd like to remove the boilerplate, yielding something along the lines of:

```
setter :: (Config -> a) -> a -> Config -> Config
x = setter confA
y = setter confB
z = setter confC
```

But I have no idea how to construct such a `setter` function. Is this even possible in (non-template) haskell or am I butting up against the syntax sugar here? If so, how would I do such a thing in template haskell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't possible with just Haskell's record system. What you want are *lenses*; this [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio) and its top answer are a good introduction. Personally, I use the [data-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens) package talked about there. (See also [data-lens-fd](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-fd) to use it with the [MonadState](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#t:MonadState) class from mtl — if you don't know what that is, just know that you should probably use it whenever you want to use lenses in a `State` monad.)

The [data-lens-template](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-template) package might be the application of Template Haskell you want; it derives lens definitions for record fields.

The other popular lens package is [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels). I prefer data-lens for its simplicity and speed; fclabels (as of version 1.0) is slightly more flexible, but you don't need that flexibility for what you want to do. (Note that due to its newly-increased flexibility, fclabels' `(:->)` type can no longer be directly translated to the simple definition of lenses, as mentioned in the Stack Overflow answer I linked.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without Template Haskell. You could use data-accessor and data-accessor-template to remove such boiler plate.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Record syntax automatically creates *getters* for you, but those are mostly useless when you want to create *setters*.