# typeOf on return type

Tags: haskell

I'm extending an answer to [Haskell setting record field based on field name string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659939/haskell-setting-record-field-based-on-field-name-string) to add a generic `getField`.  I'm using `gmapQi`, and I want to generate an error if the type of the encountered sub-element does not match the expected type.  I want the error message to include the name of the type that was encountered, as well as the name of the type expected.  The function looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Generics
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception

getField :: (Data r, Typeable v) => Int -> r -> v
getField i r = gmapQi i (e `extQ` id) r
  where
    e x = error $ "Type mismatch: field " ++ (show i) ++
                  " :: " ++ (show . typeOf $ x) ++
                  ", not " ++ (show . typeOf $ "???")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Foo = Foo Int String
  deriving(Data, Typeable)

handleErr (ErrorCall msg) = putStrLn $ "Error -- " ++ msg

main = do
  let r = Foo 10 "Hello"
  catch (print (getField 0 r :: Int))    handleErr
  catch (print (getField 0 r :: String)) handleErr
  catch (print (getField 1 r :: Int))    handleErr
  catch (print (getField 1 r :: String)) handleErr
```

The problem is, I don't know what to put in place of `"???"` to get the return type of the `getField` function (i.e. how to reify `v` from the type signature).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeOf` never evaluates its argument, so you can use any expression as long as it's of the correct type. In this case, the type of the result is the same as the return type of `e`, so you can just use `e x`.

```
getField :: (Data r, Typeable v) => Int -> r -> v
getField i r = gmapQi i (e `extQ` id) r
  where
    e x = error $ "Type mismatch: field " ++ (show i) ++
                  " :: " ++ (show . typeOf $ x) ++
                  ", not " ++ (show . typeOf $ e x)
```

This gives the expected output when run:

```
10
"Error -- Type mismatch: field 0 :: Int, not [Char]
Error -- Type mismatch: field 1 :: [Char], not Int
"Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(show . typeOf $ (undefined :: v))` if you add `forall r v.` to the start of your type signatures and turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

It'll be possible to achieve without that — usually it involves dummy helper functions to coerce the types into the form you want — but it will be very ugly and I'm not sure how.