# Overloading show method for Maybe types

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

This is followup to an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161217/performing-type-equality-in-template-haskell) I asked. Now, I am trying to modify the `toText` method so that it also handles `Maybe a` with overloaded `toText` function. Below is a code that compiles and works fine - now, I will like to overload `toText` for `Maybe a` using `toText` definition itself for other types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.List
import Data.Text (unpack, pack, Text, empty)
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Maybe (maybe)

data ToTextMethod = TTMText | TTMShow | TTMMaybe

type family ToTextHow a where
     ToTextHow Text = TTMText
     ToTextHow (Maybe b) = TTMMaybe
     ToTextHow a = TTMShow

class ToTextC a b where
      toTextC :: a -> b -> Text

instance Show a => ToTextC a (Proxy TTMShow) where
      toTextC a _ = pack (show a)

instance Show a => ToTextC (Maybe a) (Proxy TTMMaybe) where
      -- Will like to replace this with
      -- toTextC a _ = maybe empty toText a 
      toTextC a _ = maybe empty (pack . show) a 

instance ToTextC Text (Proxy TTMText) where
      toTextC t _ = t

toText :: forall a. (Show a, ToTextC a (Proxy (ToTextHow a))) => a -> Text
toText x = toTextC x (Proxy :: Proxy (ToTextHow a))
```

If I update the `toTextC` definition for `TTMMaybe` type as indicated in the comment to below:

```
instance Show a => ToTextC (Maybe a) (Proxy TTMMaybe) where
      toTextC a _ = maybe empty toText a
```

I get this error - will appreciate pointers on how to solve this overloading:

```
 Could not deduce (ToTextC a (Proxy (ToTextHow a)))
      arising from a use of ‘toText’
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:21:10-53
    In the second argument of ‘maybe’, namely ‘toText’
    In the expression: maybe empty toText a
    In an equation for ‘toTextC’: toTextC a _ = maybe empty toText a
```

**Update 1:**

Following the suggestion in comment, I fixed it using additional constraint. However, it required `UndecidableInstances` extension to be turned on! Is there a better way to do this without using `UndecidableInstances`? Perhaps some kind of type operator or function to express type-level computation?

```
instance (Show a,ToTextC a (Proxy (ToTextHow a))) => ToTextC (Maybe a) (Proxy TTMMaybe) where
      toTextC a _ = maybe empty toText a
```

Comment: It is telling you it is looking for an instance - putting that instance in the context will make it compile. You are trying to recursively apply the `toText` function, to a value of type `a`, so you need a constraint to prove that you can do so. You are trying to peform this unwrapping recursively, essentially.

Comment: @user2407038, how would you express that constraint?

Comment: The constraint is literally `ToTextC a (Proxy (ToTextHow a))`.

Comment: Note: `UndecidableInstances` is **not** a "bad" extension. It simply tells the compiler to lift the restrictions that are placed to guarantee termination of type inference. So the worst thing that can happen is that when you try to compile your code you get the compiler stuck in an infinite loop instead of getting a type error telling you that no instance could be found.

Comment: @Bakuriu, yep, that is what I am wary about. Not a bad extension but possibility of not halting is there. So, exploring if there is a better way to tell the compiler about type-level computations.