# Does Haskell have pointers/references to record members?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, member-pointers

I can create and reference relative pointers to struct members in C++ using the `::*`, `.*`, and `->*` syntax like :

```
char* fstab_t::*field = &fstab_t::fs_vfstype;
my_fstab.*field = ...
```

In Haskell, I can easily create temporary labels for record getters like :

```
(idxF_s,idxL_s) = swap_by_sign sgn (idxF,idxL) ;
```

Afaik, I cannot however then update records using these getters as labels like :

```
a { idxF_s = idxL_s b }
```

Is there an easy way to do this without coding for each record setter?

Comment: The pointer to member operators are not C but C++. Retagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A getter and setter bundled together in a first-class value is referred to as a *lens*. There are quite a few packages for doing this; the most popular are [data-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens) and [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels). This [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio) is a good introduction.

Both of those libraries support deriving lenses from record definitions using Template Haskell (with data-lens, it's provided as [an additional package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-template) for portability). Your example would be expressed as (using data-lens syntax):

```
setL idxF_s (b ^. idL_s) a
```

(or equivalently: `idxF_s ^= (b ^. idL_s) $ a`)

You can, of course, transform lenses in a generic way by transforming their getter and setter together:

```
-- I don't know what swap_by_sign is supposed to do.
negateLens :: (Num b) => Lens a b -> Lens a b
negateLens l = lens get set
  where
    get = negate . getL l
    set = setL l . negate
```

(or equivalently: `negateLens l = iso negate negate . l`<sup>1</sup>)

In general, I would recommend using lenses whenever you have to deal with any kind of non-trivial record handling; not only do they vastly simplify pure transformation of records, but both packages contain convenience functions for accessing and modifying a state monad's state using lenses, which is incredibly useful. (For data-lens, you'll want to use the [data-lens-fd](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-fd) package to use these convenience functions in any `MonadState`; again, they're in a separate package for portability.)

---

<sup>1</sup> When using either package, you should start your modules with:

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Category
```

This is because they use generalised forms of the Prelude's `id` and `(.)` functions — `id` can be used as the lens from any value to itself (not all that useful, admittedly), and `(.)` is used to compose lenses (e.g. `getL (fieldA . fieldB) a` is the same as `getL fieldA . getL fieldB $ a`). The shorter `negateLens` definition uses this.

Answer (score 5):

What you want here is first-class record labels, and while this does not exist in the language, there are several packages on Hackage which implement this pattern. One of these is [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-1.1.0.2), which can use Template Haskell to generate the required boilerplate for you. Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Category
import Data.Label
import Prelude hiding ((.))

data Foo = Foo { _fieldA :: Int, _fieldB :: Int }
  deriving (Show)

$(mkLabels [''Foo])

main = do
  let foo = Foo 2 3

  putStrLn "Pick a field, A or B"
  line <- getLine

  let field = (if line == "A" then fieldA else fieldB)

  print $ modify field (*10) foo
```