# Haskell: "how much" of a type should functions receive? and avoiding complete "reconstruction"

Tags: function, haskell, types

I've got these data types:

```
data PointPlus = PointPlus
    { coords :: Point
    , velocity :: Vector
    } deriving (Eq)

data BodyGeo = BodyGeo
    { pointPlus :: PointPlus
    , size :: Point
    } deriving (Eq)

data Body = Body
    { geo :: BodyGeo
    , pict :: Color
    } deriving (Eq)
```

It's the base datatype for characters, enemies, objects, etc. in my game (well, I just have two rectangles as the player and the ground right now :p).

When a key, the characters moves right, left or jumps by changing its `velocity`. Moving is done by adding the `velocity` to the `coords`. Currently, it's written as follows:

```
move (PointPlus (x, y) (xi, yi)) = PointPlus (x + xi, y + yi) (xi, yi)
```

I'm just taking the `PointPlus` part of my `Body` and not the entire `Body`, otherwise it would be:

```
move (Body (BodyGeo (PointPlus (x, y) (xi, yi)) wh) col) = (Body (BodyGeo (PointPlus (x + xi, y + yi) (xi, yi)) wh) col)
```

Is the first version of `move` better? Anyway, if `move` only changes `PointPlus`, there must be another function that calls it inside a new `Body`. I explain: there's a function `update` which is called to update the game state; it is passed the current game state, a single `Body` for now, and returns the updated `Body`.

```
update (Body (BodyGeo (PointPlus xy (xi, yi)) wh) pict) = (Body (BodyGeo (move (PointPlus xy (xi, yi))) wh) pict)
```

That tickles me. Everything is kept the same within `Body` except the `PointPlus`. Is there a way to avoid this complete "reconstruction" by hand? Like in:

```
update body = backInBody $ move $ pointPlus body
```

Without having to define `backInBody`, of course.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for "lenses". There are several different packages for lenses; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio) is a good summary of them.

My understanding is that a lens on a data type `a` for some field `b` provides two operations: a way to get the value of `b` and a way to get a new `a` with a different value of `b`. So you would just use a lens to work with the deeply nested `PointPlus`.

The lens packages provide useful functions for working with lenses as well as ways of generating lenses automatically (with template Haskell) which could be very convenient.

I think they are worth looking into for your project, especially because you are likely to encounter similar problems with nesting in other places thanks to the structure of your data types.

Comment: That's perfect, especially with the automatic generation!
What about the `move` function? Is it better for it to take the whole `Body` or only its `PointPlus` part?

Comment: @L01man I also describe a concrete example very similar to yours in a blog post of mine on lenses [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html)

Comment: Your step-by-step explaination helped me understand fully lenses.

Comment: Don't you think Haskell should implement lenses by default? Types are part of the languages, and record syntax is kind of redundant with lenses but less powerful.