# Shorthand way for assigning a single field in a record, while copying the rest of the fields?

Tags: haskell, record

Let's say I have the following record ADT:

```
data Foo = Bar { a :: Integer, b :: String, c :: String }
```

I want a function that takes a record and returns a record (of the same type) where all but one of the fields have identical values to the one passed as argument, like so:

```
walkDuck x = Bar { a = a x, b = b x, c = lemonadeStand (a x) (b x) }
```

The above works, but for a record with more fields (say `10`), creating a such function would entail a lot of typing that I feel is quite unnecessary.

Are there any less tedious ways of doing the same?

Comment: Record syntax for updating exists, but quickly gets cumbersome. Take a look at [lenses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio) instead.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Yes, there's a nice way of updating record fields. In GHCi you can do --

```
> data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: String }  -- define a Foo
> let foo = Foo { a = 1, b = 2, c = "Hello" }         -- create a Foo
> let updateFoo x = x { c = "Goodbye" }               -- function to update Foos
> updateFoo foo                                       -- update the Foo
Foo {a = 1, b = 2, c = "Goodbye" }
```

Comment: The `RecordWildCards` extension can be nice as well, to “unpack” fields in a scope. For updates it’s not quite as nice though: `incrementA x@Foo{..} = x { a = succ a }`

Comment: BTW, in Frege (a Haskell for the JVM) you would define the function as ```updateFoo x = x.{ c = "Goodbye" }``` (note the ```.``` operator).

Comment: Nice video by the way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YScIPA8RbVE

Comment: Thanks. Sadly been a long time since I wrote any Haskell!

Answer (score 40):

This is a good job for [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fclabels/1.1.4.3/doc/html/Data-Label.html#g:2):

```
data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Int , c :: String }

test = Foo 1 2 "Hello"
```

Then:

```
setL c "Goodbye" test
```

would update field 'c' of 'test' to your string.

Comment: And lenses-like packages often define operators in addition to functions for getting and setting fields.  For example, `test $ c .~ "Goodbye"` is how `lens` would do it iirc.  I'm not saying this is intutitive, but once you know the operators then I expect it would come as easily as `$`.

Comment: Do you know where _setL_ has gone? I'm importing _Control.Lens_, but ghc is reporting that _setL_ is undefined.

Comment: use set instead of setL

Comment: That is awful procedual thinking. in Haskell, don’t say what it does, but what it *is*. That’s kinda the point of functional programming. Writing `test { c = "Goodbye" }` is a much more natural way of saying “`test`, but with `c` being `"Goodbye"`”. Whoever designed that `setL` function, missed the whole point of functional programming. … If record syntax has flaws, which it does, record syntax itself needs a fix. Not something that effectively turns Haskell into a C-like again.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine did you have a look how lenses work under the hood? It looks imperative on the surface but it's absolutely wild category-theory-type-magic-trickery at it's finest. Check out: https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/lens/

Comment: @NiklasGruhn: Well, that makes it even worse. If I’m programming in a functional language, something should not be crammed into an imperative look in the first place. And while I like not dumbing down things, it should also not be incomprehensible magic trickery either. They key word is *emergence*. Lots of power *and* from very simple parts. Elegance and (coding) efficiency are related words. … What good is simplicity, if you can’t do anything anymore? (e.g. iPhones) And what good is power, if you can’t actually use it? (e.g. academic porn like this).…  And I like category theory, so… :)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine Totally agree. I just thought this might be the angle to convince you to give lenses a try. Anyway, lenses are not about crunching the pesky imperative idioms into Haskell just so the normi devs feel more comfortable. Lenses solve real problems and exert nice functional properties like composability. Just because it syntactically resembles imperative style doesn’t have to mean it’s a bad concept

Answer (score 27):

You don’t need to define auxiliary functions or employ lenses. Standard Haskell has already what you need. Let’s take the example by Don Stewart:

```
data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Int , c :: String }

test = Foo 1 2 "Hello"
```

Then you can just say `test { c = "Goodbye" }` to get an updated record.