# why can't I add Ints to the last Ints of a tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples

I have to a data Student and a type Class:

```
data Student = Student {nome :: String
                        , stdNumber :: Int
                        , approvedClass :: Int
                        , failedClass :: Int
                        }
type Class = [Student]
```

and I'm trying do add to the approvedClass number and failed of a Student but i'm don't know how to do it . I already have this:

```
addClasses :: Student-> Int -> Int -> Student
addClasses student aC fC = (student _ _ (approvedClass+aC) (faileClass+fC))
```

But it doesn't work and i can't understand why? or how to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` is only valid in pattern matching, and does not automatically denote "keep this field the same". Instead, [use record update syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955676/5923139):

```hs
addClasses :: Student-> Int -> Int -> Student
addClasses student aC fC =
    student { approvedClass = approvedClass student + aC
            , failedClass = failedClass student + fC
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to record syntax, you would need to match each field explicitly to reuse in constructing a new `Student` value.

```
addClasses :: Student -> Int -> Int -> Student
addClasses (Student w x y z) aC fC = Student w x (y + aC) (z + fC)
```